# Easily Detecting IE Version with JavaScript and userAgent

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Looking for the slickest way to quickly ascertain the current version of Internet Explorer being used, if at all, purely in JavaScript. I want to favor terseness and practicality over extreme precision with all ancient IE user agent strings.

```
var IE = /*???*/;

if (IE && IE<9){
  // degraded web experience
} else {
  // pro web experience
}
```

Comment: Browser sniffing and comments like "This page is best viewed in *<some browser>*" are seriously *passé*.

Comment: Woa! Shouting won't help. The comment on browser sniffing is far more passive agressive then the word *passé*, perhaps some emoticons will help? :-) ;-p Anyhow, far better to use feature detection and perhaps present a message like "this site does not support your browser, it requires *<list of minimum browser versions>*" or similar. There is no standard for the user agent string and for a great many minor browsers it is completely wrong (e.g. the browser in my TV is Linux based but pretends to be some version of IE).

Comment: @RobG: I can't allow a potentially broken layout to go without a notice -- sometimes, clients don't have a budget that allows for IE8(-) support. Even if a Linux TV sees the warning, it will serve as a disclaimer for why the layout is all messed up. Eh, I don't know, I'll think about it. I felt like I was fighting the good fight, encouraging legacy users to consider upgrading -- for the good of the web? Maybe at the expense of the user's convenience.. Some people are at work. Still, I'll never go back to IE6(-) compatibility. A disclaimer is appropriate for these users, yeah?

Comment: Sure, but who get's the good stuff and who doesn't should be based on feature detection, not the contents of the user agent string. E.g. my (less than 1 year old) TV browser get's the message "You don't have Flash" from some sites when in fact it does, but they prevent viewing if it's less than a certain version. I can't help that, I'm beholden to the TV manufacturer for updates and web sites to support older versions of Flash (which works on other sites and used to work on sites that now say they wont). I don't know what feauture of the new version they require, so I'm left in the dark. :-(

Answer (score 0):

**Here's what I've come up with:**

```
var IE = (function getIEVersion(){
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
    var regex = /MSIE ([0-9]{1,}).*;/;
    var result = regex.exec(navigator.userAgent);
    return result ?parseInt(result[1]) :0;
  } else return 0;
})();

////////////

if (IE && IE<9) alert("Your browser sucks!");
else console.log("We're cool");
```

- `IE` is always an integer
- `IE = 0` when the browser is not Internet Explorer
- I've tested it to work in IE11's emulation modes.
- IE11 is the first IE to no longer declare itself in the userAgent string, so IE11+ will appear as non-IE to this function (IE=0)

*I'm glad to know if anyone sees any issues with this technique, or know of a better one.*

Comment: Why do you want to detect it may I ask?

Comment: @null: Just to notify legacy users that they should upgrade their browser for the full experience.

Comment: Couldn't you just use Conditional Comments?

Comment: @null: I used to use conditional comments for this, which was fine, but now I want the functionality easily accessible from a lightweight JS library. Spawning conditional comments isn't quite appropriate if it isn't necessary.